# vuejs send an empty value and response is the field required

Tags: php, laravel-5, vue.js

Today I started to work with vuejs.

and my form is just having field (name) and submit button

so when I tried to debug the post request it send whatever I put in the input field and after submitting the form its only send empty string and the response is the field name is required

This is all my code:

the JS app file

```
Vue.http.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = document.querySelector('#token').getAttribute('value');

new Vue({ el: '#create-form',

data: {
newName: '',
},

methods: {

onSubmitForm: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var name = this.newName;
    this.newName = '';
    this.$http.post('manufacturer', name);
}
}
});
```

and this is my Store Method it work fine with normal form

```
public function store(ManufacturerRequest $request) { 
Manufacturer::create($request->all()); 
return redirect()->action('ManufacturersController@index');

}
```

http://laravel.io/bin/wJJdb#1,18,22,36

T tried even write the whole code from start to see what I miss =( but didn't find any thing and don't know where is the problem exactly.

Comment: Please post the code here on SO in a readable way. The bin is of no help in this case as it isn't runnable.

Comment: ok i just edit the question

Comment: My guess is that `this` is not referring to the vm in that callback. Can you add the `#create-form` template so we can see how it is being invoked?

Comment: In the "post" you're posting just the value name. A regular form post a string concatenating name and value, like so `name=John&last=Snow`. Now, you don't have to do that manually, you can have in data as an object
`data:
{
    formdata:{newName:""}
}
`
and when you post, pass the option emulateJSON to true https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource/blob/master/docs/http.md#options